# Concurrent access and scaling of "non-managed" utility class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, concurrency, ejb, cdi

If I have a stateful class that requires a utility-like stateless class to perform an operation on it. These stateful classes are kept in a list in a container (stateful) class. This is what I would do with plain Java:

```
class Container {
    List<Stateful> sfList;
}

class Stateful {

    List<String> list;

    void someMethod() {
        list.add("SF");
        Stateless.foo(this);
}

class Stateless {
    public static void foo(Stateful sf) {
        sf.getList().add("SL");
    }
}
```

and inside `main` this is the procedure:

```
Stateful sf = new Stateful();
sfList.add(sf);
sf.someMethod();
```

Now with JavaEE CDI I would do:

```
class StatefulBean {

    List<String> list;

    @Inject
    StatelessBean slsb;

    void someMethod() {
        list.add("SF");
        slsb.add(this);
}

@Stateless
class StatelessBean {
    public void add(StatefulBean sfsb) {
        sfsb.add("SL");
    }
}
```

In this case all StatefulBean could access a shared pool of StatelessBean with no concurrency issues and it will scale properly with requests.

However, since `Stateful` is not a managed bean I can't inject into it and so I used the utility class instead. Also I'm creating `Stateful` with a constructor so I can't inject into it the stateless bean (I will get a NPE using it).

My questions are:

- Are there concurrency and scalabilty differences between the stateless injection approach (provided it would work) and the utility class approach?
- How can I make the EE injection approach work?

Comment: Does your second code fragment contain some typos? Your use of `...Bean` is inconsistent

Comment: @SteveC fixed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there concurrency and scalabilty differences between the stateless injection approach (provided it would work) and the utility class approach?

Yes there are, primarily around the loss of management. The way you're instantiating `Stateful` on every invocation of the method, there's no pooling involved. This is going to lead to you creating more instances than you probably need.

Another loss is on the scalability side. Where the container will manage the passivation and activation of your stateful bean in a distributed environment, the manual approach will see to it that you manage your own activation and passivation.

> > Since `Stateful` is not a managed bean..

Incorrect. According to the [CDI Spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#what_classes_are_beans), any java class that meets the listed criteria (in your case, a default no-arg constructor) is a managed bean. That means that you could `@Inject` `StatelessBean` into `Stateless` and the container would oblige. To allow this level of management, you'll need to set `bean-discovery-mode=all` in your *beans.xml*.

Even with the (apparently needless) circular reference, normal Java concurrency rules apply: as long as the state that you're manipulating is not static or in a static class, you're threadsafe. Each threaded call to that static method still operates on a separate stack, so no problems there.

> How can I make the EE injection approach work?
>   If you need on-demand instantiation of `Stateless`(or any other bean really), use the CDI [`Instance`](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/learn/userguide/CDI-user-guide.html#_obtaining_a_contextual_instance_by_programmatic_lookup) to programmatically obtain a managed instance of any class you want. You can now add something like this to `Container`:

```
@Inject @Dependent Instance<Stateful> stateful;

    @PostConstruct
     public void createStateless(){
         //instantiate sfList;
         sfList.add(stateful.get()); //execute as many times as you need
     }
```

Comment: I fixed the copy-paste mistakes, sorry. The situation is that I have the `Stateful` class which requires utility methods to manipulate its state. I cannot `@Inject` into it the stateless utility class because I am instantiating it via a constructor, so the container can't take care of injections. This is why I'm using a utility class with static methods instead of a `@Stateless` bean. If there is a way I can add `Stateful` objects (with or without `@Stateful`) to the list in `StatefulBean2` in a way that would make it work I'm good with that, or if you have another suggestion to make it work.

Comment: @Mark - my answer is still valid: normal java concurrency rules apply. As long as `stateless` doesn't maintain any state, your code is threadsafe

Comment: I have `bean-discovery-mode=all` and I get a NPE when accessing a method in the injected bean. The bean containing the injected bean is created with a constructor. In my code example it's `sf = new StatefulBean()` and then `sf.someMethod()` give an NPE on the line `stsb.foo(this);`

Comment: @Mark - *all* the beans must be managed by CDI. The entire dependency tree must be CDI managed. That means no `new StatefulBean()`. Why can't you `@Inject StatefulBean` where you need it?

Comment: I need it inside a list like I show in `StatefulBean2`. I'm open to suggestions. How do I replace: `sb = new StatefulBean(); list.add(sb)` in a method?

Comment: @Mark I'm not following. Why a List? I'm trying to avoid a bunch of guesswork here - are you trying to get a brand new instance of `StatefulBean` on demand, or are you trying to instantiate a specific number of them at startup?

Comment: on demand. Whenever I instantiate one of them I need to add it to the list.

Comment: @Mark - use `@Inject @New Instance<Stateful> stateful;` to provide injected access to `Stateful` beans. Wherever you need them, you can then call `stateful.get()` to obtain a brand new managed instance of that bean. Alternatively, you can use the `@Dependent` annotation instead of `@New`. If you restructure your question to fit your actual requirements, I'll add this to the answer. Your original question was about concurrency, not injection

Comment: I restructured and clarified the question. I'm also throwing in a small bounty as compensation for the mess and it seems I will post more questions in this area because I read and tried a few things with `Instance` and `@Dependent` that you revealed to me and am getting some things I don't understand. I hope you would help me with those too

Comment: @Mark - you mean you're still unable to obtain a managed instance of `Stateful` using `@Dependent @Instance<Stateful>`?

Comment: I am able. What you said works for the most part. I just have a few problems as a result which I will ask in another question. I restructured the question so that you can add all this to your answer and also if possible answer the scalabilty side as well.

Comment: I've updated the answer. The scenario you're building around is quite contrived and is predicated on a flawed design. Best to re-evaluate your entire approach instead of trying to work around a flawed design with complicated code @Mark

Comment: Thanks. Why is this considered a flawed design?

Comment: @Mark - I don't see the need for `Stateless` as in, there's nothing happening in that class, that can't happen in `Stateful`. I find the need to pass an entire EJB into another class (via static method call) a design smell. Either inject it or pass data only into a singleton bean